# Change address where Prometheus node exporter listens in systemd drop-in unit

Tags: debian, systemd, prometheus

I have a this drop-in unit:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/prometheus-node-exporter.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
Environment=ARGS=--web.listen-address=localhost:9101
```

It is relative to this unit from Debian package `prometheus-node-exporter` (`stretch-backports` version):

```
# /lib/systemd/system/prometheus-node-exporter.service
[Unit]
Description=Prometheus exporter for machine metrics
Documentation=https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter

[Service]
Restart=always
User=prometheus
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/prometheus-node-exporter
ExecStart=/usr/bin/prometheus-node-exporter $ARGS
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
TimeoutStopSec=20s
SendSIGKILL=no

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`/etc/default/prometheus-node-exporter` sets `ARGS=""`, i.e. the node exporter's default port 9100 applies. The drop-in is meant to change this to 9101 and let the service listen only on `localhost`.

After `systemctl start prometheus-node-exporter` the service listens on `:::9100` (`tcp6`). However, if I comment-out `EnvironmentFile` in the unit file it listens on `127.0.0.1:9101` (`tcp`), as I want it to. So it seems as if `EnvironmentFile` from the unit keeps precedence over `Environment` in the drop-in unit.

Why does the drop-in not override the unit in choosing the value of `ARGS`? What am I missing and can I change the default listening address with a custom drop-in unit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From `man systemd.exec`:

> EnvironmentFile= ...
>              Settings from these files override settings made with Environment=. If the same variable is set twice from these files, the
>   files will be
>              read in the order they are specified and the later setting will override the earlier setting.

So you need to specify an `EnvironmentFile` to override the setting in the unit file:

```or-tag-here
# /etc/systemd/system/prometheus-node-exporter.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/prometheus.conf
```

and actual config:

```or-tag-here
# cat /etc/prometheus.conf
ARGS=--web.listen-address=localhost:9101
```